# Como mudar o menu file que está sendo usado no Android Menu Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

Eu quero saber se é possível mudar o arquivo de menu sendo usado pelo drawer navigation menu
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Exemplo: Ao entrar nesse if que está em azul, deve ser selecionado para uso outro arquivo de menu no drawer menu navigation. 
-Isso realmente é possível? 
-Se sim, como fazer? 
-Se não, há uma boa solução para fazer isso?

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente: você quer mudar o que é exibido na drawer ao clicar em um de seus itens?

Comment: é exatamente isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um meio, mas dependendo do que você pretende fazer não sei se seria usável, pois ele também fecha o `Navigation Drawer`, mas prosseguindo...

É possível sim mudar o arquivo que está sendo usado pelo `Navigation Drawer`, primeiramente você "limpa" o menu que está sendo usado com o método `Clear()` e depois infla o novo menu:

```
navView.getMenu().clear(); //limpa o menu inflado (e fecha o navigation drawer)
navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav); //infla o novo menu
```

Caso não seja isso o que deseja, você pode detalhar um pouco mais do que precisa.